# Ignoring styles while using <p>

Tags: html, css

I am using following

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/abpEB
```

you can see a simple html+css code. And I can't understand why text is not colored in red :(
Strange fact that when I'm using `<div>` instead `<p>` — color is red.

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: `p` is just a single paragraph. You should not use it for structuring code as far as I know. You cannot nest paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of you are using `<p>` tag inside of another `<p>` tag, html render them as two separate `<p>` tag, you can see this by inspecting element in chrome. you can use `span` tag inside `<p>` tag.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the first css class and use this code

```
p.street {
 color: red;    
}
```